model.summary not working as intended when using text vectorization layer in tensorflow
Hey guys,
I am writing a small NN model using a text vectorization layer in tensorflow (I am using Kaggle Notebook). Here is the code:
vocab_size = 1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens = vocab_size)
encoder.adapt(X_train)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),output_dim=16,mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])

But when I call model.summary(), i get this:
model summary
But when i write this same block of code in Google Colab, it works perfectly.
Hoping for an explanation. Thank You in advance.

Hi @Moonis Javed,The issue you're encountering might be due to the difference in TensorFlow versions between Kaggle Notebooks and Google Colab. TensorFlow versions on different platforms can have subtle differences, including how the TextVectorization layer behaves.
Kaggle Notebooks might be using a TensorFlow version where the TextVectorization layer is not yet fully integrated into the model summary, resulting in the layer not being shown. This could be due to a variety of reasons, including different TensorFlow version policies, platform-specific modifications, or configurations.
